# Docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, containers

*Admittedly, the issue relates to ROS2, but the problem arises in relation to running a Docker container so I believe it is more suitable here.*

I'm trying to install this distribution according [to the tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Setup-ROS-2-with-VSCode-and-Docker-Container.html) and the problem occurs when trying to run the Docker container from within VSCode (by the command "Dev Containers: (Re-)build and Reopen in Container"); I get these errors every time:

```
[2024-02-26T15:16:48.272Z] docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /tmp/.X11-unix.
[2024-02-26T15:16:48.342Z] Error: Command failed: docker run --sig-proxy=false -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount source=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src,target=/home/ws/src,type=bind --mount source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind,consistency=cached --mount source=/dev/dri,target=/dev/dri,type=bind,consistency=cached --mount source=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/../cache/foxy/build,target=/home/ws/build,type=bind --mount source=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/../cache/foxy/install,target=/home/ws/install,type=bind --mount source=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/../cache/foxy/log,target=/home/ws/log,type=bind --mount type=volume,src=vscode,dst=/vscode -l devcontainer.local_folder=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src -l devcontainer.config_file=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json -e DISPLAY=unix:0 -e ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=1 -e ROS_DOMAIN_ID=42 --net=host -e DISPLAY=:0 --privileged --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-src-564c0f3878223de91739e23245cb3f558814064f074bdef27b05dc35d748ce9d-uid -c echo Container started
[2024-02-26T15:16:48.360Z] Command failed: /usr/share/code/code /home/przemek/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.338.1/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/przemek/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-9daee105-fc17-46c4-8b2e-11d0bb212bf11708960596697 --workspace-folder /home/przemek/ws_type_one/src --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/przemek/ws_type_one/src/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root
```

I believe that the first one is the cause of the rest of them.
Interestingly, `/tmp/.X11-unix` exists and I have no idea how to solve it. I found on the Web that packages coming from Snap were the problem, but my Docker and VSCode are not installed that way.

I will be extremely grateful for any suggestions.